# How does the number of votes voted by an user is less for this month and high for this week?

Tags: discussion, voting, users

Number of Votes voted by a particular user in Pro Webmasters for this **Week is 40** but for this **month is 21**. This count looks wrong for me since week count is higher than month count. Does it is a problem with the system or Am I missing any thing?

Screenshot for reference:

**Week count:**

[image]

**Month Count:**

[image]

Comment: I actually noticed this on Mi Yodeya the other day. My guess is that the week starts from Sunday, and the Month starts from the first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This month started yesterday (1<sup>st</sup> of December), while this week started one day earlier (last Sunday). You can see the exact days taken into account in a tooltip when hovering the curser over the buttons that allow you to switch between the week and month view.